# PHPStorm - Binding a Keyboard Shortcut to Close Current File

Tags: phpstorm

I recently moved from Windows to OS X and transferred my PHPStorm preferences in the process.  On my Windows machine, I remember I had bind ctrl + w to close the current window.  This is what PHPStorm listens for on my Mac too.  I'd like to be more consistent in how I close my sub-windows in my applications and want to change this binding to cmd + w.  I can't seem to find where in the "Keymaps" section this binding is set at.  Does anyone know the name of this action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried searching your keymap for "Close" ? This will narrow list of possible actions **a lot**.

In any case: `Preferences | Keymap`

Action: **Main Menu | Window | Editor Tabs | Close**